# send SMS from my application Wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sendmessage

Hi I am developing a Wp8 application and I want to know can I send an SMS message without having to go into the native messaging application or does it have to go in to it. Cud i use a webservice to send the message from my app or is their better way to send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an SMS, in about 5 lines of code, you should look into Twilio. Incredibly easy to get started, only pay for what you use, nicely document rest api and best of all its is a proven/mature technology.

https://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: yes i was thinking of a webservice, but I was trying to make sure that you can't send a message from your own application, which I feel is stupid

Comment: Indeed it's not stupid.  The amount of Android apps that turned out to be malware that simply sent SMS messages to premium numbers, enriching the developers and cheating the users, was quite staggering at one point.  WP8 doesn't all it for this very reason.  Like most things that people find "stupid" about WP8, it's all due to security.

Comment: Actually the next major version of Windows Phone could allow sending SMS directly from the app according to "leaks" (read: no one can trust them :-) ), but I presume it will not be as unconstrained as with Android, and will require some careful handling.